# Probabilistic Approximation of non-linear Dynamical System by Diffusion Process

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-processes, approximation-theory, large-deviations, discrete-dynamical-systems

---

*Setting*

Suppose I have a discrete dynamical system given by:
$$
X^{n+1} = f(X^{n})
\qquad X^0 =x
,
$$
where $f$ is some diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ to itself, and some $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

---

*Question*

Given a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion $W_t$ and integer $n$.

When does there exist, functions $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, $\rho:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and a predictable-process $u_t$ such that for small $\sigma > 0$:
$$
Z_t^{\sigma}= \int_0^t\tilde{f}(Z_{s}^{\sigma},u_s)ds + \sigma W_t  \qquad Z_0^{\sigma} = x
$$

satisfies the "small deviation-type principle:"

- (Approximation of $X^n$ by $Z_t$) for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $n_{\epsilon}>0$ satisfying:
  $$
  \limsup_{\sigma \to 0}
  \mathbb{P}\left\{
  \|Z_t^{\sigma} - X^n\|<\epsilon:\, (\forall t \in [n,n+1))
  \right\}>\rho(\epsilon) \qquad (\forall n\geq n_{\epsilon})
  $$
- (Rate function $\rho$ decays to $0$) $$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \rho(t) = 0.$$

---

### *Ideally:*

Can $\tilde{f}$ be written down explicitly (I don't need $u_t$ to be explicit)?

Comment: I made some edits since there was no explicit need for the control $U^n$ in the discrete system.

Comment: You're right, I didn't need the control.  Thanks!